# How to check if opensuse-12.3 iso-release download is corrupted?

Tags: linux, opensuse, k3b

I want to upgrade from openSuSE 12.2 to 12.3.

Therefore I have burned a ISO file of the openSuSE 12.3 distribution (32bit).
To be precise I did this twice since I wondered, that this process resulted in a 4.2 G File
Is this wrong - is this correct!?

Well since the first download also ended up in a 4,2 G file I just downloaded another file - also 4.2 G. What is wrong here!?

Attached the K3B burning protocol - I took the header and the footer.

What do you say - is this all correct?

Can I continue in my upgrade process well? I guess no.
I have to tell the notebook that it have to boot from the DVD. But - how do I do that!?

```
Devices
-----------------------
TEAC DV-W28S-R S.0B (/dev/sr0, CD-R, CD-RW, CD-ROM, DVD-ROM, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD-R doppelschichtig, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD+R doppelschichtig) [DVD-ROM, DVD-R sequenziell, Zweischichtige DVD-R sequenziell, Zweischicht-DVD-R-Sprung, DVD-RAM, DVD-RW Eingeschränktes Überbrennen, DVD-RW sequenziell, DVD+RW, DVD+R, Zweischichtige DVD+R, CD-ROM, CD-R, CD-RW] [SAO, TAO, SAO/R96P, SAO/R96R, Eingeschränktes Überschreiben, Sprung zwischen DVD-Schichten] [%7]

K3b::DataTrackReader
-----------------------
reading sectors 0 to 2213887 with sector size 2048. Length: 2213888 sectors, 4534042624 bytes.
using buffer size of 128 blocks.
Read a total of 2213888 sectors (4534042624 bytes)

System
-----------------------
K3b Version: 2.0.2
KDE Version: 4.8.5 (4.8.5) "release 2"
QT Version:  4.8.1
Kernel:      3.4.33-2.24-desktop

Used versions
-----------------------
cdrecord: 1.1.11

cdrecord
-----------------------
/usr/bin/wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
scsidev: '/dev/sr0'
devname: '/dev/sr0'
scsibus: -2 target: -2 lun: -2
Linux sg driver version: 3.5.27
Wodim version: 1.1.11
SCSI buffer size: 64512
Beginning DMA speed test. Set CDR_NODMATEST environment variable if device
communication breaks or freezes immediately after that.
TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
Driveropts: 'burnfree'
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   :
Vendor_info    : 'TEAC    '
Identification : 'DV-W28S-R       '
Revision       : 'S.0B'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Current: 0x0011 (DVD-R sequential recording)
Profile: 0x002B (DVD+R/DL)
Profile: 0x001B (DVD+R)
Profile: 0x001A (DVD+RW)
Profile: 0x0016 (DVD-R/DL layer jump recording)
Profile: 0x0015 (DVD-R/DL sequential recording)
Profile: 0x0014 (DVD-RW sequential recording)
Profile: 0x0013 (DVD-RW restricted overwrite)
Profile: 0x0012 (DVD-RAM)
Profile: 0x0002 (Removable disk)
Profile: 0x0011 (DVD-R sequential recording) (current)
Profile: 0x0010 (DVD-ROM)
Profile: 0x000A (CD-RW)
Profile: 0x0009 (CD-R)
Profile: 0x0008 (CD-ROM)
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc DVD-R(W) driver (mmc_mdvd).
Driver flags   : SWABAUDIO BURNFREE
Supported modes: PACKET SAO
Drive buf size : 1605632 = 1568 KB
FIFO size      : 12582912 = 12288 KB
Speed set to 11080 KB/s
Track 01: data  4324 MB        
Total size:     4965 MB (491:58.50) = 2213888 sectors
Lout start:     4966 MB (492:00/38) = 2213888 sectors
Current Secsize: 2048
HINT: use dvd+rw-mediainfo from dvd+rw-tools for information extraction.
Blocks total: 2298496 Blocks current: 2298496 Blocks remaining: 84608
Starting to write CD/DVD at speed   8.0 in real SAO mode for single session.
Last chance to quit, starting real write in    2 seconds.
   1 seconds.
   0 seconds. Operation starts.
Waiting for reader process to fill input buffer ... input buffer ready.
Performing OPC...
Sending CUE sheet...
Starting new track at sector: 0
Track 01:    0 of 4324 MB written.
Track 01:    1 of 4324 MB written (fifo  96%) [buf  67%]  27.3x.
Track 01:    2 of 4324 MB written (fifo  99%) [buf  93%]   0.0x.
Track 01:    3 of 4324 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf  89%]   1.0x.
Track 01:    4 of 4324 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf  89%]   2.1x.
Track 01:   96 of 4324 MB written (fifo  98%) [buf  99%]   2.4x.
Track 01:   97 of 4324 MB written (fifo  98%) [buf  99%]   2.0x.
Track 01:   98 of 4324 MB written (fifo  99%) [buf  93%]   2.0x.
Track 01:   99 of 4324 MB written (fifo  99%) [buf  93%]   2.0x.
Track 01: 4323 of 4324 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf  58%]   5.2x.
Track 01: 4324 of 4324 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.7x.
Track 01: Total bytes read/written: 4534042624/4534042624 (2213888 sectors).
Writing  time:  818.772s
Average write speed   4.1x.
Min drive buffer fill was 55%
Fixating...
Fixating time:   20.115s
/usr/bin/wodim: fifo had 71416 puts and 71416 gets.
/usr/bin/wodim: fifo was 0 times empty and 11126 times full, min fill was 58%.

cdrecord command:
-----------------------
/usr/bin/wodim -v gracetime=2 dev=/dev/sr0 speed=8 -sao driveropts=burnfree -data -tsize=2213888s -
```

Comment: I tried to straighten your question, however some points remain unclear to me: You downloaded 2 times and burned 2 times, right? What makes you think that something is wrong? And please don't include multiple questions in one. If you can't boot from your DVD drive, raise a seperate question providing more informations about your setup, but please use the search function before.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be irritated that the [download page](http://software.opensuse.org/123/de) states "4.7GB DVD" -- this refers only to the medium, i.e. a DVD, single sided. The image file might as well be smaller.

Simply use the provided MD5 checksum (http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/12.3/iso/openSUSE-12.3-DVD-i586.iso.md5) to verify that your download is correct. Use the following command line in the directory where you downloaded the ISO image:

```
md5sum -c openSUSE-12.3-DVD-i586.iso.md5
```

The burning process itself looks fine -- every byte was written:

```
Track 01: Total bytes read/written: 4534042624/4534042624 (2213888 sectors).
```

Use the "Verify" option in `k3b` if you want to check the burned data afterwards.